# Syntactic error in bash case statement

Tags: bash, switch-statement

```
#!/bin/bash

dia=$(date +"%d")
echo $dia
mes=$(date +"%m")

case $mes
01)  $mes='Jan';;
02)  $mes='Feb';;
03)  $mes='Mar';;
04)  $mes='Apr';;
05)  $mes='May';;
06)  $mes='Jun';;
07)  $mes='Jul';;
08)  $mes='Aug';;
09)  $mes='Sep';;
10)  $mes='Oct';;
11)  $mes='Nov';;
12)  $mes='Dec';;
esac
```

The error is the following

```
./check_brute_force.sh: line 18: syntactic error near unexpected element `01'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` statement needs an `in`, e.g.:

```
case $mes in
```

Comment: And you should not use $ in mes='Jan'

Comment: Thanks a lot, both answers helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Missing "in" keyword

```sh
case $mes in
```